# Hbase Indexer with Lily Solr deletes indexed data on adding New Indexer

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucene, hbase

I use Hbase Indexer with Lily Solr (Lucene 4.4) with my CDH4 System.

I have 2 servers where lily-solr runs and 5 Indexer Configurations to Index different data datatype , I too use lily-server for storing data in Hbase.

When I add indexer configuration and request for batch build , initially it indexes all data and gradually it deletes all indexes .

I use the following way to add index :

```
asset_idx01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n asset_idx01 -z spotlight-prod-cluster01 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster01:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c asset_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n asset_idx01 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

asset_idx02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n asset_idx02 -z spotlight-prod-cluster02 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster02:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c asset_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n asset_idx02 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

brightcove_idx01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n brightcove_idx01 -z spotlight-prod-cluster01 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster01:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c brightcove_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n brightcove_idx01 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED 

brightcove_idx02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n brightcove_idx02 -z spotlight-prod-cluster02 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster02:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c brightcove_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n brightcove_idx02 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED 

fortune_idx01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n fortune_idx01 -z spotlight-prod-cluster01 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster01:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c fortune_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n fortune_idx01 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

fortune_idx02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n fortune_idx01 -z spotlight-prod-cluster02 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster02:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c fortune_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n fortune_idx02 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

populist_idx01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n populist_idx01 -z spotlight-prod-cluster01 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster01:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n populist_idx01 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

populist_idx02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n populist_idx02 -z spotlight-prod-cluster02 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster01:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n populist_idx02 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

twitter_stat_idx01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n twitter_stats_idx01 -z spotlight-prod-cluster01 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster01:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c twitter_stats_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster01

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n twitter_stats_idx01 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED

twitter_stat_idx02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer add-indexer -n twitter_stats_idx02 -z spotlight-prod-cluster02 -cp solr.mode=classic -cp solr.shard.1=http://spotlight-prod-cluster02:7575/solr -r org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilyIndexerComponentFactory -cp solr.sharder=org.lilyproject.indexer.hbase.mapper.LilySharder -c twitter_stats_indexconfig.xml -cp lily.zk=spotlight-prod-cluster02

/usr/lib/hbase-indexer/bin/hbase-indexer update-indexer -n twitter_stats_idx02 --batch BUILD_REQUESTED
```

Can anyone please help me in knowing the various root cause, So that I can rectify.

I follow the following steps

1. Import Data to Hbase
2. Start Lily Server
3. Start Hbase Indexer
4. Add Indexer Configuration to Hbase
5. Request Batch Build as mentioned above.